# Use images of my resources - Compact Framework

Tags: c#, image, windows-mobile, compact-framework, picturebox

I add an Image to my project resources (Windows Mobile 6.1). I want to use this image to set the PictureBox.Image property of some PictureBoxes I have in my Form. I try the following code:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.my_image;
pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.my_image;
pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources.my_image;

...

pictureBoxN.Image = Properties.Resources.my_image;
```

The problem is that sometimes the image is displayed  only in some of the PictureBox (I get a `TargetInvocationException` when I try to set the image), and not in all. Why? How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**:

The StackTrace of the InnerException:

> in Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr(PAL_ERROR ar) in
>   System.Drawing.Bitmap._InitFromMemoryStream(MemoryStream mstream) in
>   System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream) in
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeConstructorInfo
>   rtci, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean
>   verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) in
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   in System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters) in
>   System.Resources.ResourceReader.CreateResource(Type objType, Type[]
>   ctorParamTypes, Object[] ctorParameters) in
>   System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadBitmap(Int32 typeIndex) in
>   System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObjectV2(Int32 pos,
>   ResourceTypeCode& typeCode) in
>   System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObject(Int32 pos,
>   ResourceTypeCode& typeCode) in
>   System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetObject(String key, Boolean
>   ignoreCase) in System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name,
>   CultureInfo culture) in
>   Icons_Control.Properties.Resources.get_glass_empty() in
>   Icons_Control.ListItem.set_CompletitionStatus(eCompletionStatus value)
>   in Icons_Control.ListItem..ctor() in
>   Icons_Control.ListItem..ctor(eItemType type) in
>   Icons_Control.MainForm.menuItem3_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e) in
>   System.Windows.Forms.Menu.ProcessMnuProc(Control ctlThis, WM wm, Int32
>   wParam, Int32 lParam) in System.Windows.Forms.Form.WnProc(WM wm, Int32
>   wParam, Int32 lParam) in
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam,
>   Int32 lParam) in Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
>   in System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm) in
>   Icons_Control.Program.Main()

Comment: A `TargetInvocationException` usually has an `InnerException` that provides a bit more detail.

Comment: I'm pretty sure about my answer, just curious how large is your image and how many picture boxes were you assigning it to?

Comment: @Alan about 60 Kb, i can't display more than 5 image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are running out of memory or other resources. Image resources are a bit dangerous. Every time you get a resource, a new one is created. You're likely only wanting to create one instance of my_image, and you likely want to dispose of it after you are done using it.

```
Image myImage = Properties.Resources.my_image;

pictureBox1.Image = myImage;
pictureBox2.Image = myImage;
pictureBox3.Image = myImage;
pictureBox4.Image = myImage;
...
pictureBoxN.Image = myImage;

// Later on when you are done using it
myImage.Dispose();
```

Very important on most CF apps to not waste memory.

Comment: You could also wrap Alan's code in a `try...catch` block to display a more user friendly message and keep going.